# How can I prepend some data to an json decoded array in particular place

Tags: php, json

My task is to prepend a data to an array, which I get from decoding JSON file. I am very newbe in php and especially in php + JSON data. I am able to prepend data to JSON file, but on the wrong place, and somehow by prepending this data it modifyes to `{"0":{my prependet data}...}`. I do not want to have "0", I want to have structure like in the code below.

php code:

```
$current_data = file_get_contents('reports.json');

$array_data   = json_decode($current_data, true);

$extra_data = array(
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'date' => $_POST["date"],
    'message' => $_POST["message"]
);
array_unshift($array_data[0], $extra_data);
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);
file_put_contents( 'reports.json', $final_data );
```

JSON file has this structure:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "date": "30.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Polly",
      "date": "27.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I get now in JSON is:

```
{"0":{"name":"Name from $extra_data",
      "date": "Date from $extra_data",
      "message":"some words from $extra_data"}, 
 "reports": [
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "date": "30.09.2017",
          "message": "some words 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Polly",
          "date": "27.09.2017",
          "message": "some words 2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

What I want to get is following:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "name": "Name from $extra_data",
      "date": "Date from $extra_data",
      "message": "some words from $extra_data"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "date": "30.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Polly",
      "date": "27.09.2017",
      "message": "some words 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: as far as i can see all you have to do is change this `array_unshift($array_data[0], $extra_data);` to this `array_unshift($array_data['reports'], $extra_data);`

Comment: @Mattigins thank you very much, works perfectly! How can I mark your answer as solvation of my question?

Comment: *"My task is to prepend a data to an array"* -- the JSON part is irrelevant. Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Then check the endless list of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that PHP provides. About a handful of them can be used to put a value in front of an array ([`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php), [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) etc).

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I am glad you got it figured out. Just an upvote on my comment is fine :) Wasn't worth writing a whole answer so i thought i'd just comment.

Comment: I wrote a whole answer anyway :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially creating an index at 0 and sticking it there. Since your array doesn't use indexes since it is an associative array all you would need to do is change the following line

```
array_unshift($array_data[0], $extra_data);
```

To this

```
array_unshift($array_data['reports'], $extra_data);
```

That way it makes sure it sticks the data in the "reports" part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're unshifting into the json object, not the reports array.
Something like this:

$current_data = file_get_contents('reports.json');

$array_data   = json_decode($current_data, true);

```
$current_data = file_get_contents('reports.json');

$array_data   = json_decode($current_data, true);

$extra_data = array(
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'date' => $_POST["date"],
    'message' => $_POST["message"]
);
$reports = $array_data['reports'];
array_unshift($reports, $extra_data);
$final_data = json_encode($reports);
var_dump($final_data);
```